# Does Restlet support reactive programming?

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

Does anyone know if Restlet supports reactive programming for handling its request? If not, are the available implementations (BIO & NIO)? I understand there is a [problem/bug with Restlet 2.2.x](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/996) .

How is Restlet async handled? I will like to know the design behind this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NIO module available that you can use:

- http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/nio
- https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/tree/master/modules/org.restlet.ext.nio

And there are async capabilities as shown in this test case with the response handler on the request, around line #100 or so:

- https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.test/src/org/restlet/test/engine/connector/AsynchroneTestCase.java

Regarding the issue with the Camel integration, it's not clear yet where the problem lies, whether it's in the integration, or in Restlet Framework per se. More investigation is needed.

For the design behind the async handling, don't hesitate to dive in the sources of the project, after all, it's open source! You can start with looking at the [Request](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/Request.java) and its `setOnResponse()` method which is the method setting the callback handler.